# Show that $Z^2 + Y^3 + X^5$ is irreducible in $\mathbb C[X,Y,Z].$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials, integral-domain, polynomial-rings

Here is the question I want to answer:

Let $\mathbb C[X,Y,Z] \cong \mathbb C^{[3]}.$ Define rings $$ A = \mathbb C[Y,Z]/(Z^2 + Y^3) \text{ and } B = \mathbb C[X,Y,Z]/(Z^2 + Y^3 + X^5) = \mathbb C [x,y,z]$$
where $x,y,z$ are the images of $X,Y,Z$ under the standard projection $\mathbb C [X,Y,Z] \rightarrow B.$

$(b)$ Show that $Z^2 + Y^3 + X^5$ is irreducible in $\mathbb C[X,Y,Z].$ Conclude that $B$ is an integral domain.

**Here is my trial:**

[image]
[image]

1- Can anyone give me a feedback on my trial please? specifically,I feel like my reasoning that it is an integral domain is not correct.

Could anyone show me how to find this isomorphism and its kernel and image please?

**EDIT:**

3-I also found this question here:

[Show that $f(x,y,z)=x^2-y^2z$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3028756/show-that-fx-y-z-x2-y2z-is-irreducible-in-mathbbcx-y-z?rq=1) but still I am confused about the general procedure and the specific details I should calculate to solve those kinds of problems, could anyone clarify this to me please?

Comment: I'm not reading all of that text (especially because it's scanned), but the general procedure is particularly simple when you have a polynomial which is quadratic in one of the variables: apply the quadratic formula. As $\Bbb C[x,y,z]\subset\Bbb C(x,y)[z]$ is an inclusion of UFDs, every factorization of your polynomial in the smaller ring comes from an appropriate grouping of factors in the bigger ring, up to possibly an adjustment by units. So if the results of the quadratic formula are in $\Bbb C[x,y,z]$, your polynomial factors, and if not, it doesn't.

Comment: You do not need to read the whole text .... they are just trials which maybe true or false ..... ok seems like you are explaining a simple thing but could you show me the details please ? specifically because I do not understand what do you mean by $\mathbb C[x,y,z] \subset \mathbb C(x,y)[z]$? not also that the variables in $\mathbb C$ sometimes capital letters and sometimes small ones @KReiser

Comment: @Confusion in the comment of KReiser, the variables $x,y,z$ are not necessarily those of $B$, you can apply the same thing to $X,Y,Z$. What is meant by $\mathbb C[x,y,z] \subset \mathbb C(x,y)[z]$ is that the polynomial ring  $\mathbb C[x,y,z] $ (polynomials on three variables over $\mathbb C$) are naturally included in the polynomial ring $\mathbb C(x,y)[z]$ (polynomials on ONE variable over $\mathbb C(x,y)$, the field of fractions of $\mathbb C[x,y]$).

Comment: Could you please give me a simple example of applying what KReiser said @Javi .... it is not clear to me how the field of fraction will enter into the play.

Comment: @Confusion consider the polynomial $Z^2-X^2-2XY-Y^2$, you can factor this polynomial as a polynomial in $\mathbb C(X,Y)[Z]$ as $(Z+Y+X)(Z-Y-X)$, and that is actually a factorization in $\mathbb C[X,Y,Z]$ too.

Comment: Gotcha ....  so is my proof of irreducibility above in my question wrong @Javi Also, Can you show me an ordered logical descent solution to my question .... I feel like I am so confused and having conflicting ideas.

Comment: Well, I'm not an expert so I might be wrong, but if you try to solve the quadratic equation  $Z^2+X^3+Y^5=0$ for the variable $Z$, you will notice that the solutions are the square roots of $-X^3-Y^5$, which are not elements of $\mathbb C(x,y)$, so you cannot factor the polynomial in $\mathbb C(x,y)[z]$, let alone in $\mathbb C[x,y,z]$.